# Flashforge Adventurer 3 Spool mounting

Tags: flashforge-adventurer-3, flashforge

I have just purchased the above 3D printer and the mount for the spool does not fit the new spool. The external spigots are too large and there is no axle shaft that would have helped.

This is a photo of the spool:

[image: Spool]

Has anyone else had this problem?

---

*I am looking for something that fitted in original hole/area.*

Answer (score 1):

From a comment by the OP *(posted as a Community wiki)*:

> The supplier has just forwarded [a solution](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4002193) but it is not what I was hoping for as I was looking for something that fitted in original hole/area.

Supplier suggestion (image):
[image]